# Time limit exceeded , in Markligic Cts:Search

Tags: marklogic

I have about 53,00,000 document in my marklogic server and each document contains one  record.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
  declare namespace pa = "http://www.contata.com/pa";  
  let $query :=  
         cts:or-query((  
            cts:element-word-query(  
              xs:QName("pa:name"), "SMITH"  
            ),  
            cts:element-word-query(  
              xs:QName("pa:address-1"),  ""   
            ),  
            cts:element-word-query(  
              xs:QName("pa:address-2"),  ""   
            ),
            cts:element-word-query(   
              xs:QName("pa:address-3"),  ""   
            ),  
             cts:element-word-query(  
              xs:QName("pa:city"),  ""   
            )  
                    )) return   

cts:search(fn:doc(),$query)[5100000 to 5300000]
```

when I execute above mentioned query it takes and long time to execute and gives the following error

[1.0-ml] XDMP-EXTIME: cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:or-query((cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("pa:name"), "SMITH", ("lang=en"), 1), cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("pa:address-1"), "", ("lang=en"), 1), cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("pa:address-2"), "", ("lang=en"), 1), ...))) -- Time limit exceeded

but when I execute `cts:search(fn:doc(),$query)[1000 to 2000]` it executes succesfully.

One More question, if I have loaded all my documents then how can I create indexes on them after loading from RecordLoader Utility.

Answer (score 4):

Look into the 'unfiltered' option, and also consider using 'search:search'.

You could also increase the time limit, but probably won't want to. With filtered search getting to the 500000th result requires checking 500000 documents, which may require up to 500000 disk reads. If your disk can manage 100 every second, that is 5000 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You are showing 200.000 search results. Try to show less at once. If you'd use Query Console or CQ profiler, you would see that not cts:search is taking so much time, but getting those 200k docs.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks  for your reply,

when i run this query it also gives the same error but now i am trying to get only 10 records.

`cts:search(fn:doc(),$query)[5300000 to 5300010]`